# Excel VBA - Formatting "Fri Feb 27 08:45:00 CST 2015" into a usable date

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I am currently in the process of building a database for reporting purposes. the original data will come from an automated data source that sends a csv to a shared location. I have some processes that go out and get the data and then put it in a shared location, I then have an excel document that has connections set up to the data and that will then connect to the data and refresh when the workbook is opened. This process is complete but the issue that I'm running into is that the original data source is exporting the csv it is formatting the date as "Fri Feb 27 08:45:00 CST 2015" (for example). I need to get this into a format of "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" At this time getting the output format from the vendor changed is not a viable option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I honestly have no idea even where to start with this so I have no code to post. I will say that this will be done on a large amount of rows. so for example it might be B2:B10000

Comment: Be aware that any simple string manipulation may run afoul of time zones. If all your times are local and you want to process them as local, it's doable, but otherwise things could get nasty.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put that, they are all going to be processed as local and are local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format you're getting is always the same, you can use a regular expression and then just rebuild it into a `Date`, then format it:

```
'Requires reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
Sub ParseDateExample()
    testValue = "Fri Feb 27 08:45:00 CST 2015"
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = ".+\s(.+)\s(\d{1,2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s.+(\d{4})"
        If .Test(testValue) Then
            Dim matches As Object
            Set matches = .Execute(testValue)
            Dim temp As String
            temp = matches(0).SubMatches(0) & "/" & matches(0).SubMatches(1) & "/" & _
                   matches(0).SubMatches(3) & " " & matches(0).SubMatches(2)
            If IsDate(temp) Then
                Debug.Print Format$(CDate(temp), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I made an edit on my post, I'm going to have to do this on a large amount of cells, Do you think this would be good inside a loop? such as maybe a for each or do while?

Comment: @SamL yes you could do this inside a loop.

Comment: Awesome, I went ahead and did this while using for each loop and it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Not considering several time zones:

```
Sub convertDate()

Dim str As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim mm As String
Dim convDate As String

str = "Fri Feb 27 08:45:00 CST 2015"

arr() = Split(str)

Select Case arr(1)
Case "Jan": mm = "01"
Case "Feb": mm = "02"
Case "Mar": mm = "03"
Case "Apr": mm = "04"
Case "May": mm = "05"
Case "Jun": mm = "06"
Case "Jul": mm = "07"
Case "Aug": mm = "08"
Case "Sep": mm = "09"
Case "Oct": mm = "10"
Case "Nov": mm = "11"
Case "Dec": mm = "12"
End Select

convDate = mm & "/" & arr(2) & "/" & arr(5) & " " & arr(3)

MsgBox (convDate)

End Sub
```